# Echarts on legend selection event not working

Tags: javascript, php, echarts

I am fixing a chart used in a product. The issue is when the legend is selected the x-axis should change the dates according. Currently, the code of my graph is:

```
// initializing graph
var months_graph_by_visitors = ec.init(document.getElementById("MyPluginOne_months_graph_by_visitors"));
// graph functionality 
var months_graph_by_visitors_option = {
            tooltip: {
              position: function (p) {
                if (
                  $("#MyPluginOne_months_graph_by_visitors").width() - p[0] <=
                  200
                ) {
                  return [p[0] - 170, p[1]];
                }
              },
              formatter: function (params, ticket, callback) {
                var month_name = "";
                if (params.seriesIndex == "0" && data.stats_data.this_month_users_data.length != 1 ) {
                  var s_date = moment(params.name, "D-MMM", true).format(
                      "MMM DD"
                    ),
                    month_name = moment(s_date, "MMM DD", true)
                      .add(-1, "months")
                      .format("D-MMM");
                } else {
                  month_name = params.name;
                }
                return (
                  params.seriesName +
                  "<br />" +
                  month_name +
                  " : " +
                  params.value
                );
              },
              show: true,
            },
            color: [
              data.stats_data.graph_colors.visitors_last_month,
              data.stats_data.graph_colors.visitors_this_month,
            ],
            legend: {
              data: [
                data.stats_data.visitors_last_month_legend,
                data.stats_data.visitors_this_month_legend,
              ],
              orient: "horizontal",
            },
            toolbox: {
              show: true,
              color: ["#444444", "#444444", "#444444", "#444444"],
              feature: {
                magicType: {
                  show: true,
                  type: comp_graph_type === 'bar' ? ["bar", "line"] : ["line", "bar"],
                  title: {
                    line: "line",
                    bar: "bar",
                  },
                },
                restore: { show: true, title: "Restore" },
                saveAsImage: { show: true, title: "Save As Image" },
              },
            },
            xAxis: [
              {
                type: "category",
                boundaryGap: false,
                data: data.stats_data.date_data,
              },
            ],
            yAxis: [
              {
                type: "value",
              },
            ],
            series: [
              {
                name: data.stats_data.visitors_last_month_legend,
                type: comp_graph_type,
                smooth: true,
                itemStyle: {
                  normal: {
                    areaStyle: {
                      type: "default",
                    },
                  },
                },
                data: data.stats_data.previous_month_users_data,
              },
              {
                name: data.stats_data.visitors_this_month_legend,
                type: comp_graph_type,
                smooth: true,
                itemStyle: {
                  normal: {
                    areaStyle: {
                      type: "default",
                    },
                  },
                },
                data: data.stats_data.this_month_users_data,
              },
            ],
          };
 // Load data into the ECharts instance.
 months_graph_by_visitors.setOption(months_graph_by_visitors_option);
```

I want to change the values of x-axis when the legend is selected. The legend has two options:

1. visitor this month
2. visitor last month

Now if I click on visitor this month the xaxis should have this month's date and vice-versa.
In current code only **data.stats.date_data** show current month date. But I have fixed this by sending data to two variables **data.stats.this_month_date_data** and **data.stats.previous_month_date_data**. But I cannot be able to show this in the graph. I read the documentation of echarts and over there the following way was mentioned:

```
myChart.on('legendselectchanged', function(params) {
  // State if legend is selected.
  var isSelected = params.selected[params.name];
  // print in the console.
  console.log(
    (isSelected ? 'Selected' : 'Not Selected') + 'legend' + params.name
  );
  // print for all legends.
  console.log(params.selected);
});
```

I tested this but no data was logged. Can anyone guide me in this issue so that I can fix the issue.

Comment: Your echarts instance is calles `months_graph_by_visitors` not `myChart`.

Comment: I know. That is a typo. But by using ***months_graph_by_visitors*** still the legend events do not worked.

Comment: I would need to know what is stored in your variables, for example `data.stats_data.visitors_last_month_legend`. Pls make a minimal reproducable example, preferibly in the [echarts editor](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple).

Comment: It is basically the label of the Legend.

Comment: What about using axis type `time` and let echarts auto adjust the axis? [Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-simple&code=MYewdgzgLgBAJgQyggjDAvDA2lg5AJgAZ8AWAWkJTPwHZcAaGFIgXUbyNIqvwA4GmvQm2wFi5StQCcA3gFYRHcdzIBmQgJQlh7MV0mqUA_OpYsA3AChQkWImT4M2JfvwUAbJta7OEt4TpGFCFFPT8KfkZ5UN8Kfxkg7RjlYjIUDUYTYQtLSxAABygAS3AnAG9LGBgAGwBTAHNasDgALhgygF96SpgADwBBXqKINoqqqqgAT3zattxigFtahh6qhCGIABkEACNa6tHV8YAzEAAnBaQoWrO5srgO9oBZF8eyyY_Jjtwjjp6unqTQbDQ7jGBTGZzABuCGqAFdlv9ulUIDcirURtgjmMweDprMYLgdggzitcTAwAglnN7KgybjaW1aShfsjxjiwRCCUSSfSwZTqYTafg-eNGfAkAh8L8eixLB1zEA)

Comment: currently my data is like
views_current_year:{2,3,6,11,10}
current_year_dates:{2024-02-01,2024-02-02,2024-02-03,2024-02-04,2024-02-05}

views_last_year:{22,13,36,11,10}
last_year_dates:{2023-02-01,2023-02-02,2023-02-03,2023-02-04,2023-02-05}

So I have to make them one object ?

Comment: I have no idea how your chart looks like or what you are trying to tell me. Pls provide a working example of your chart.